# How to stop audio playing on websites loaded in webView?

Tags: android, audio, webview

How can I stop the audio of a video that is playing on a website in a webview after I have left the Activity? In other words, lets say I have both Activity A and Activity B. I load up a website in Activity B that is playing a video, and then press the back button to go to Activity A. My experience is that the sound continues to play while on Activity A. How can I stop this audio?

I am not doing anything special with displaying the webpage, I use a webView

```
<WebView
        android:id="@+id/fl_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

And I declare the following settings

```
flContainer = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.fl_container);

        flContainer.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        flContainer.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        flContainer.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        flContainer.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

I then display a website that has a video in it and play the video. After pressing the back button the audio continues to play. How can I stop this as there is no mediaPlayer to destroy or anything like this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either destroy the previous webview as this one will continue running in the background by default, or change the player element to something else.

Comment: Ha! Thank you, flContainer.destroy(); worked. Cheers!